# Bulk_create django

Tags: django, bulk-create

Is there a  way to dynamically keep progress of the number of instances saved in the database when using bulk_create in django

def bulk_create(
self,
objs,
batch_size=None,
ignore_conflicts=False,
update_conflicts=False,
update_fields=None,
unique_fields=None,
):

Comment: `bulk_create` runs a single query on the db. There's no way to monitor the progress.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Django-simple-History](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html#) maybe it will be useful to you. Or you can create a custom middle ware